# How to disable sorting on specific column while searching is functional

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable

I am using DataTable (http://www.datatables.net) in order to get desired functionality including sorting columns and searching within columns from Table Heading individually. Initializing is as follow which returns api and searching functionality is achieved.

$('#table2').DataTable()

Now Problem is when I have to disable sorting on checkbox and I have to use following line of code. 
`$('#table2').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ] } );`

it does apply sorting disabled on column but search functionality within column also doesn't work. Is there any way I can pass any parameter in DataTable({something}) in order to disable sorting on first column or please help me to combine (api & jquery object) method in order to achieve desired functionality.
`$('#table2').DataTable();
$('#table2').dataTable();`

```
<table class="table table-striped draggable sortable dataTable" id="table2">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center"> <input class="check_box_all no-sort" id="check_all" type="checkbox" title="Check All"></th>
        <th class="text-center">Company Name </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="check_box"></td>
        <td class="text-center">Med Assets Company</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This snippet makes input field in table heading for searching purpose

```
$('#table2 thead th').slice(3).each(function () {
    var title = $('#table2 thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
 });
```

Data Table Initialize

```
 var table = $('#table2').DataTable({
    "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",});
```

Applying the search

```
 var tableResult = table.columns().eq(0);
if (tableResult !== null) {
    tableResult.each(function (colIdx) {
        $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
            table
                    .column(colIdx)
                    .sort()
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
        });
    });
}
```

Please check jsfiddle when check box is checked it totally mess up
https://jsfiddle.net/sxgd0thm/

Comment: please show your html code.

Comment: It works - https://jsfiddle.net/skh73h1d/

Comment: Please check html is provided or you can visit jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
"aoColumnDefs": [
  { "bSearchable": true, "aTargets": [ 0,1,2,3,4,5 ] }
] } );
```

Try with "bSearchable" with allowable column search

Comment: Searching isn't working with this code, can you please check jsfiddle I have given above and recheck it once more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table2').dataTable({
   "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
      {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 1 ]}
  ]});
```

Can you try with this