# Disable search/filtering for a specific column in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, filtering

**What I am trying to achieve**

Disable my filtering function for column 8 in my table. (e.g it won't get recognized/does not care)

**What I am struggling with**

I can't manage to exclude column number 8 from my filtering. I've tried to use `.not` but cannot get that to work either. I've also attempted to use the CSS `:not` but I've heard that is not reliable enough (even though I am using it in my code). I struggle to implement this the right way.

**My question**

What would be the best option for this kind of task? How would I implement this correctly?

**What my filtering looks like**

```
$("#table_search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".table_data tr:not(:has(th))").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
});
```

**DOM**

```
<div class="table_responsive">
    <div><input type="input" id="table_search" class="form-control" placeholder="Perform a search..."></div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>thead1</th>
            <th>thead2</th>
            <th>thead3</th>
            <th>thead4</th>
            <th>thead5</th>
            <th>thead6</th>
            <th>thead7</th>
            <th>thead8</th>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="table_scroll">
        <table class="table_data">
            <tr>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row3</td>
                <td>row4</td>
                <td>row5</td>
                <td>row6</td>
                <td>row7</td>
                <td>row8</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Additional comments**

I am aware there are questions ***almost*** identical to mine and I don't know if it's because I haven't finished my morning coffee or what not. But it's a shame *(and a bit embarassing)* I struggle with tweaking and implementing their solution to my problem.

Here's a few similar questions I've taken a look at:

[Disable search filter on a specific column (this question only disables the search input for the columns itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894660/how-to-disable-a-search-filter-on-a-specific-column-on-a-datatable)

[Disable sorting for column (weird array solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634615/how-to-disable-sorting-on-specific-column-while-searching-is-functional)

[Table column search filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717772/jquery-table-column-search-filter)

Comment: Could you pls share the table code as well ?

Comment: @VasuKuncham Edited with DOM structure.